# How to get XR Controller pose and last update time in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, virtual-reality

I'm having trouble accessing the XR controller position data and the time that the data was last updated (for custom velocity calculations). I am using an ActionBasedController for this, but the XRControllerState's time value is never updated (stays at 0). Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Afraid I don't have an answer. I can offer this:
The low-level API XRNodeState does NOT have timestamps, so I have no idea how the higher-level XRControllerState can promise them at all.